# Investigate continuity of a function

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, continuity

I'm trying to investigate the continuity of the function

$\varphi(x)=\sqrt{x+10}$

My solution is the following:

Let $\varepsilon>0$ and $x_0>-10$.
Then $0<|\sqrt{x+10}-\sqrt{x_0+10}| = |\sqrt{x+10}-\sqrt{x_0+10}*\frac{\sqrt{x+10}+\sqrt{x_0+10}}{\sqrt{x+10}+\sqrt{x_0+10}}| = \frac{|x+10-x_0+10|}{\sqrt{x+10}+\sqrt{x_0+10}}\leq\frac{|x-x_0+20|}{\sqrt{x_0+10}}<\varepsilon\Leftrightarrow|x-x_0+20|<\sqrt{x_0+10}*\varepsilon=\delta$,

Therefore, it is continuous in every positive number.

For continuity in $x_0=0$:

$0\leq\sqrt{x+10}<\varepsilon\Leftrightarrow0\leq x+10<\varepsilon^2$, therefore $\delta = \varepsilon^2$ and therefore it is continuous at the whole domain..

Is my solution correct? Thanks!!

Comment: It is known that the function $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is continuous  for $x\geq 0$

Comment: Too many  upvote for a question in barely 8 minutes.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yes, and I could prove that it's continuous because sum of two continuous functions is continuous, but I I'm supposed to do it through the definition of continuity, that's why I was doing it this way.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be $|x+10-x_0-10|=|x-x_0|$?

Comment: @kingW3 Yeah, you are right.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to prove the continuity of $\sqrt{x}$. Suppose $x_{0} \neq 0$ is fixed. Take $\delta = \sqrt{x_{0}}\epsilon$ for a given $\epsilon >0$. Then, we have $$\sqrt{x_{0}}\epsilon \ge |x-x_{0}| = |(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x_{0}})(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x_{0}})| = |\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x_{0}}||\sqrt{x_{0}}||\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x_{0}}}+1|\ge \sqrt{x_{0}}|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x_{0}}|. $$
This proves continuity for $\sqrt{x}$ if $x\neq 0$. For $x=0$, take $\delta = \epsilon^{2}$. Now apply this to the translation $x \to x+10$.